# Motion detector system that can be flashed remotely

Tags: smart-home, sensors, arduino, home-security

I want to build a motion detector that performs a similar service to security
services, which notify me upon intrusion and provide video feed. The other main
requirement is that I can update the sotware remotely. (For example, I can flash over-the-air
a Particle Photon, which is [similar to Arduino](https://community.particle.io/t/programming-particle-photon-with-arduino-ide/23177).) I found [this
thread](https://docs.particle.io/tutorials/hardware-projects/hardware-examples/photon/#make-a-motion-detector-publish-and-the-console)
and [this
thread](https://community.particle.io/t/webhooks-super-simple-motion-activated-push-notifications/10322)
and still have questions on how to proceed.

I would like a board that can:

- take code in C++ or Python
- connect to a [Passive Infrared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_infrared_sensor) motion sensor
- connect to speakers for a high-pitched sound upon intrusion
- use cellular connectivity if local area network is down
- function for a long time on a power bank if power is down
- be updated remotely, as I mentioned above
- ideally, compress video to save on data usage for upload

I know that people have done this on a [Raspberry
Pi](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-motion-detector-photo-capture/),
but my main requirement is a board for which I can flash the firmware remotely
(as far as I know, the Pi and any "normal" computer does not).

Has anyone built a similar system and could give some pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't "flash" software to a pi in the same way you do a micro controller based device. You can easily update software OTA (over the air) to a Raspberry pi, just by copying the files to the device and restarting the application.

If you want to automate this sort of thing then using a service like [balena.io](https://www.balena.io/) will do it for you. You just need to package your application up into docker containers.

Comment: Yes, I've been copying new application files over SSH. One concern is with security, e.g. patch the device with new updated packages. With the Particle Photon, a new version of the application is bundled with the latest firmware, and . With Balena on the Pi, it seems that I would be able to copy a docker container with my app and call it at boot, but I don't think I could flash the firmware, right?

Comment: Balena runs on top of a very thin layer, most of it runs as a hidden container next to your application containers, it gets updated automatically. You don't need to update the low level stuff in this model. It's a different mindset to embedded development.

Comment: And if you don't run Balena, then you just use the built in package management tools to update the base OS. e.g. `apt-get upgrade` (of course you should test all of this with local devices, before updating deployed devices)

Comment: I read [the primer](https://www.balena.io/docs/learn/welcome/primer/). It seems that with Balena I would still need to maintain the device with `apt-get upgrade` and the advantage of Balena is that my application is in a container and Balena automatically updates its own OS. Is that right?

Comment: No, you only need to update the content of your containers

Comment: I learned more about it and this is exactly what I was looking for: a Particle Photon cloud service for Raspberry Pi with over-the-air updates and push notifications.