# What is the difference between Particle Photon, Argon, Xenon, Boron, etc?

Tags: arduino

For one project I have used the Particle Photon, an IoT device [similar to Arduino](https://community.particle.io/t/programming-particle-photon-with-arduino-ide/23177), and am considering changing to a different device for another project (a motion detector that [has its own question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/4769/motion-detector-system-that-can-be-flashed-remotely)). I can't find the difference between Particle products such as Photon, Argon, Xenon, and Boron; only that the Boron serves for mesh networks.

Are they just newer versions, like Raspberry Pi 2, 3, and 4? Or do they have different purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the types of radio hardware each has.

- Argon - Has a WiFi (802.11) + Bluetooth 5 radio
- Boron - Has an LTE cellular + Bluetooth 5 + Zigee radio
- Xenon - Has Bluetooth 5 + Zigbee radio
- Photon - Has a WiFi (802.11b/g/n) radio

You can find the datasheets for all the devices here https://docs.particle.io/datasheets/wi-fi/photon-datasheet/

Comment: I wish one board did WiFi + LTE Cellular. [This thread](https://community.particle.io/t/can-new-mesh-boards-use-regular-wifi/45168) suggests using a combination of Boron + Argon for that effect and that Particle is aware of the interest.